# Click Event Not Firing - AJAX jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, anchor

I am using data-file anchor tags to keep the user inside the web app.

Sample HTML

```
<div class="products_content">    
<a data-file="salt.html?v=1"><img src="assets/images/template/salt.jpg" width="125" height="125" /></a>
```

Sample js

```
$('.products_content a').on('click', function(){
    changePage( $(this).attr('data-file') );
});
```

The click event isnt firing, and I have no idea why, because I am using very similar code for the Nav and it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my changePage function, not sure if it is needed.

```
function changePage(fileName) {
    $('.content_container').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 500, function () {
        $('.content_loading_container').load('assets/content/' + fileName, function () {
            $('.content_container').delay(250).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        });
        if (fileName == 'home.html?v=1') {
            $('.page').addClass('home');
        } else {
            $('.page').removeClass('home');
        }
        if (fileName == 'services.html?v=1') {
            $('.content_container').addClass('services');
        } else {
            $('.content_container').removeClass('services');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. in Sample HTML, there is no **</div>**, which might be a typo;
2. You may try delegate:

   ```
   $(document).delegate('.products_content a', 'click', function(){
       changePage( $(this).attr('data-file') );
       return false;
   })
   ```

Comment: Hi Rongsir, there is a </div> I just for got to include it in the sample. And the code you suggested seems to be working! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

As you have it your code should work.

```
<div class="products_content">    
<a data-file="salt.html?v=1"><img src="assets/images/template/salt.jpg" width="125" height="125" /> </a>

$('.products_content a').on('click', function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

Here it is in [a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6CNtj/)

Replace your changePage() code with an alert as I have done above to determine if it is the click that is failing or if it is something in changePage() that is failing.

Comment: Hi Stuart, thanks for the tip. I added the click alert as you suggested and it never poped up. So that narrows it down that the click is failing.